# Fatal Error "Class not found" Facebook Ads SDK

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to get the Facebook Ads SDK for PHP installed and working on my server, but I am experiencing some issues that I can't figure out.

This is the way I have the SDK installed on my server:

```
/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/ads-sdk/ -> (listing sub directories)
      /examples/
      /src/
      /test/
      autoload.php
      index.php
```

I have an index.php file sitting in the "ads-sdk" directory.

I am just attempting to include some files from the SDK into my index.php file as follows:

```
require (__DIR__ . '/autoload.php');
require_once(__DIR__ .'/src/FacebookAds/Api.php');
require_once(__DIR__ .'/src/FacebookAds/Object/AdUser.php');
require_once(__DIR__ .'/src/FacebookAds/Object/Fields/AdAccountFields.php');
require_once(__DIR__ .'/src/FacebookAds/Object/Fields/ConnectionObjectFields.php');
require_once(__DIR__ .'/src/FacebookAds/Object/Fields/ConnectionObjectTypes.php');

use FacebookAds\Api;
use FacebookAds\Object\AdUser;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdAccountFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\ConnectionObjectFields;
use FacebookAds\Object\Values\ConnectionObjectTypes; 

Api::init($app_id, $app_secret, $access_token);
```

I am using an autoloader in the index.php file, and here is the code for that:

```
    spl_autoload_register(function ($class)
    {
          // project-specific namespace prefix
          $prefix = 'FacebookAds\\';

          // base directory for the namespace prefix
          $base_dir = defined('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR') ? FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR : __DIR__ . 'src/FacebookAds/';

         // does the class use the namespace prefix?
         $len = strlen($prefix);
         if (strncmp($prefix, $class, $len) !== 0) {
              // no, move to the next registered autoloader
              return;
         }

         // get the relative class name
         $relative_class = substr($class, $len);

         // replace the namespace prefix with the base directory, replace namespace
        // separators with directory separators in the relative class name, append
        // with .php
        $file = $base_dir . str_replace('\\', '/', $relative_class) . '.php';

       // if the file exists, require it
       if (file_exists($file)) {
           require $file;
       }
  });
```

index.php throws a Fatal Error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'FacebookAds\Object\AbstractCrudObject' not found in /var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/httpdocs/ads-sdk/src/FacebookAds/Object/AdUser.php on line 34
```

This is line 34 of AdUser.php:

```
 namespace FacebookAds\Object;

 use FacebookAds\Object\Fields\AdUserFields;
 use FacebookAds\Object\Traits\CannotCreate;
 use FacebookAds\Object\Traits\CannotDelete;
 use FacebookAds\Object\Traits\CannotUpdate;
 use FacebookAds\Object\Traits\FieldValidation;
 use FacebookAds\Cursor;

 class AdUser extends AbstractCrudObject {  <-- line 34
```

I am new to namespaces in PHP, and cannot figure out what could be going wrong, and why the AbstractCrudObject class cannot be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using composer to include the SDK into your code (it makes this all really simple). There is a walkthrough of how you should set up composer, where to get it, and how to use it on the Github README.

- https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-ads-sdk
- http://getcomposer.org - You can read more about composer here.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to update this question for anyone coming here in 2019:

New SDK now called [Business SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/business-sdk)

```
    Create composer.json with the following contents:

    {
        "name": "name/my_test_php_app",
        "type": "project",
        "require": {
            "facebook/php-business-sdk": "^3.0.0"
        },
        "authors": [
            {
                "name": "Your Name",
                "email": "some@email.com"
            }
        ]
    }


    Install the SDK by running the following command in your terminal window:

    composer install
```